# Recommend me a mantra to overcome fear and nervousness

Tags: mantras

Often I get nervous and I want to overcome the same. I know for sure that some Sanskrit mantra can help me to overcome this problem.

So can you recommend me a mantra to overcome fear and nervousness?

Comment: @Gowtham, go for the Gayatri Mantra, its the most powerfull, secondly all mantras some or the other way do what you want.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you "Hanuman Chalisa".

Comment: "How to overcome fear". Chanting mantras is one way, for sure. But self-inquiry. Who am I, what am I afraid of. what Will happen worst case. How will I be affected. This will destroy all your fears eventually, because you will soon understand that in the looong run, nothing really matters that much as we make it out to be. :) All the best!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mantra recommendations. So it can be opinion based and people may unknowingly suggest wrong mantras.

Comment: Might be late to answer the question, but here is an excellent version of hanuman chalisa. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANk4fmRNyuE&list=PLOJWMozcY9B21AYvYznkKKE5lt2G37qPf&index=1

Comment: There are mantras in Vedas called Abhaya Mantras which particularly are meant to make one fearless..But any mantra will work when obtained from a Guru..Chanting mantras upon taking them from books or online resources is mentioned in Scriptures as sin..So don't do it..

Comment: Sadhguru jaggi vasudev's [Brahmananda swaroopa's chant](http://isha.sadhguru.org/blog/video/brahmananda-swaroopa-chanting/) has proven benefits for your problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can chant following mantras daily:

- Gayatri Mantra

  ```
  ॐ भूर्भुव: स्व: तत्सवितुर्वरेण्यं । भर्गो देवस्य धीमहि, धीयो यो न: प्रचोदयात् ।।
  ```
- Panchakshara Mantra

  ```
  ॐ नमः शिवाय ।।
  ```
- Raam Naam

  ```
  राम राम....
  ```

In case you have time then you can either read the Hanuman Chalisa or hear the Hanuman chalisa from .mp3 player (The best one is Gulshan Kumar's Hanuman Chalisa). Reading/Hearing Hanuman Chalisa with concentration just for once will decrease a lots of your fear and nervousness because Hanuman is also very well known as *Sankatmochan* (problem resolver).

Comment: Sankatmochan : RESOLVING PROBLEMS

Comment: The first two must only be chanted if given by a guru.

Comment: Gyatri is restricted and won't work for uninitiated or ineligible people.

Comment: Gayatri is not to be chanted without adhikara and without initiation.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the Kali Santarana Upanishad, one of the primary 108 Upanishads:

> hare krishna hare krishna
> krishna krishna hare hare
> hare rama hare rama
> rama rama hare hare
>
> iti shodashakam namnam
> kali-kalmasha-nashanam
> natah parataropayah
> sarva-vedeshu drishyate

Verses 5-6

Translation:

> The sixteen names of the Hare Krishna maha-mantra: hare krishna hare krishna krishna krishna hare hare, hare rama hare rama rama rama hare hare destroy all the inauspiciousness of the age of Kali. This is the conclusion of all the Vedas.